# Boost issue while uisng parser "error: no matching function for call to ‘move_to"

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, ubuntu-18.04, boost-spirit

I am getting this error: no matching function for call to ‘move_to error when i try to use boost parser.
below is exact code.

```
#include <regex>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_flush_multi_pass.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

using ascii::space;
using ascii::char_;
using ascii::alpha;
using x3::string;
using x3::lit;
using x3::attr;
using x3::eoi;

namespace parser{

struct context_data_tag;

template <class T>
struct context_data_
{
    T const& parser;
    std::string &msg;
    int &newline_count;
};

template <class T>
context_data_<T> create_context_data(T const& p, std::string &m, int &n) {return {p,m,n};}

struct sep_parser : x3::parser<sep_parser> {
    typedef x3::unused_type attribute_type;
    static bool const has_attribute = true;
    template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename RuleContext, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context const& context, RuleContext& r, Attribute& a) const
    {
        auto& data = x3::get<context_data_tag>(context);
        return data.parser.parse(first,last, context, r, a);
    }

};

auto const sep = sep_parser{};

typedef std::vector<std::string> Record;

x3::rule<class record, Record> const record = "record";
x3::rule<class lf, char> const lf = "lf";

auto const CR = char_(0x0D);
auto const LINEBRK = x3::omit[lf] | (x3::omit[CR] > x3::omit[lf]) | eoi;
auto const textdata = (char_("-! ~@#$%^&*(){}[]<>.?a-zA-Z_0-9/\\+=|:;,'\t`") - sep);
auto const non_escaped = *textdata;
auto const dblequote = char_('"') >> '"';
auto escaped = '"'
                >> *((char_ - '"')
                | CR
                | lf
                | dblequote
                ) >> '"';
auto const field = escaped | non_escaped;
auto const record_def = (field % sep) > LINEBRK;


BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(record);


class record
{
    public:
        template <typename Iterator, typename Exception, typename Context>
        x3::error_handler_result
        on_error(Iterator&, Iterator const& last, Exception const& x, Context const& context)
        {
            Iterator end = x.where();
            while (end != last && *end != '\n') end++;
            std::ostringstream stringStream;
            stringStream
                << "expecting a field here> "
                << std::string(x.where(), end)
                ;

            auto& data = x3::get<context_data_tag>(context);
            data.msg = stringStream.str();
            return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
        }
};

}

bool parseFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    int _linenum = 1;
    std::string _error_msg;
    char _delimchar = ',';
    int _newline_count;
    auto const separator = x3::ascii::char_(_delimchar);
    std::ifstream stream = std::ifstream(filename);

    auto parser_data = parser::create_context_data(separator, _error_msg, _newline_count);
    auto parser_context = x3::make_context<parser::context_data_tag>(parser_data);

    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> base_irerator_type;
    boost::spirit::multi_pass<base_irerator_type> iter = boost::spirit::make_default_multi_pass(base_irerator_type(stream));
    boost::spirit::multi_pass<base_irerator_type> end = boost::spirit::make_default_multi_pass(base_irerator_type());

    parser::Record rec;

    bool r = parser::record.parse(iter, end, parser_context, x3::unused, rec);

    return r;

}
```

This is error:
/home/ubuntu/Test/WorkSpace/boost_test/src/parser.cpp:125:77:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp:196:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘move_to(char&, std::__cxx11::basic_string&, boost::mpl::identityboost::spirit::x3::traits::container_attribute::type)’
196 |         detail::move_to(src, dest, typename attribute_category::type());

/home/ubuntu/Test/WorkSpace/boost_test/src/parser.cpp:125:77:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp:86:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::enable_if<mpl_::bool_, void>’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::spirit::x3::traits::move_to(Source&&, Dest&) [with Source = char; Dest = std::__cxx11::basic_string]’:

I am using boost_1.77.0

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In functional terms?

Comment: I am trying to parse file.

Comment: What file? What's in it? I can sort of see fragments of the intended grammar from your code, but (a) it seems highly overcomplicated (b) I'm missing the expected input/output to validate whatever I can come up with to help.

Comment: Are you merely trying to _validate_ the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really figure out where you were going, so I reshaped some things notably

- using `x3::with` instead of manually using implementation details (`rule<>::parse`) and shuffling with contexts
- your `lf` parser exposes an attribute (which unnecessarily assumes it must always be a single char...) yet it is only ever used in `omit[]` context (`a % b` always implicitly `a % omit[b]`)
- lots of other stuff needs to be omitted, yet isn't (CR... why not just `lit('\r')` or indeed, `'\r'`)
- Not using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE as we don't have translation units nor recursive rules
- `*textdata` matches zero-length sequences. That creates problems it when using it to parse a variable-length file. So, I changed it to check for `eoi`.
- you have an error-handler, but there are no relevant expectation points

[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/qscPdeb4q)

```
//#include <regex>
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/multi_pass.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace parser {
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;
    using ascii::char_;

    struct ParamsTag;

    template <class T> struct Params {
        T const&     sep;
        std::string& msg;
        int&         newline_count;
    };

    template <class T, typename... Other>
    Params(T const&, Other&&...) -> Params<T>;

    struct sep_parser : x3::parser<sep_parser> {
        using attribute_type = x3::unused_type;
        static bool const has_attribute = true;
        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename RCtx, typename Attr>
        bool parse(It& f, It const& l, Ctx const& ctx, RCtx& r, Attr& a) const
        {
            auto& sep = x3::get<ParamsTag>(ctx).sep;
            return sep.parse(f, l, ctx, r, a);
        }
    };

    auto const sep = sep_parser{};

    struct HeaderData {
        std::string col, col_type;
    };

 // using Header = std::vector<HeaderData>;
    using Field  = std::string;
    using Record = std::vector<Field>;

    template <typename T> static inline auto as(auto p, char const* name = "as")
    {
        return x3::rule<struct tag, T>{name} = p;
    }

    auto EOL      = x3::eol | x3::eoi;
    auto textdata = char_("-! ~@#$%^&*(){}[]<>.?a-zA-Z_0-9/\\+=|:;,'\t`") - sep;
    auto unquoted = as<Field>(*textdata);

    auto dblequote = "\"\"" >> x3::attr('"');
    auto quoted    = '"' >> *(dblequote | ~char_('"')) >> '"';

    auto field  = as<Field>(!x3::eoi >> (quoted | unquoted), "field");
    auto record = as<Record>((field % sep) > EOL, "record");

} // namespace parser

auto parseFile(fs::path filename)
{
    // int           _linenum = 1;
    std::string   _error_msg     = "success";
    char          _delimchar     = ',';
    int           _newline_count = 0;
    auto const    separator      = x3::char_(_delimchar);
    std::ifstream stream(filename);

    using Base  = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
    auto iter   = boost::spirit::make_default_multi_pass(Base(stream));
    auto params = parser::Params{separator, _error_msg, _newline_count};

    std::vector<parser::Record> result;
    auto file = x3::with<parser::ParamsTag>(params)[*parser::record] > x3::eoi;
    if (!x3::parse(iter, {}, file, result))
        throw std::runtime_error("error: " + _error_msg);

    return result;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main()
{
    auto recs = parseFile("input.txt");
    fmt::print("Parsed: \n - {}\n", fmt::join(recs, "\n - "));
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed:
 - ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
 - ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
 - [" cool ", "that's \"nice\"", "new\nline is acceptable", "bye"]
```

And the debug output (if enabled):

```
<record>
  <try>a,b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n</try>
  <field>
    <try>a,b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n</try>
    <as>
      <try>a,b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n</try>
      <success>,b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n"</success>
      <attributes>[a]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n"</success>
    <attributes>[a]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" </try>
    <as>
      <try>b,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" </try>
      <success>,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" c</success>
      <attributes>[b]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" c</success>
    <attributes>[b]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" co</try>
    <as>
      <try>c,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" co</try>
      <success>,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" coo</success>
      <attributes>[c]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" coo</success>
    <attributes>[c]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool</try>
    <as>
      <try>d,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool</try>
      <success>,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool </success>
      <attributes>[d]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool </success>
    <attributes>[d]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool "</try>
    <as>
      <try>e\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool "</try>
      <success>\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ",</success>
      <attributes>[e]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>\n1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ",</success>
    <attributes>[e]</attributes>
  </field>
  <success>1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","</success>
  <attributes>[[a], [b], [c], [d], [e]]</attributes>
</record>
<record>
  <try>1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","</try>
  <field>
    <try>1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","</try>
    <as>
      <try>1,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","</try>
      <success>,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","t</success>
      <attributes>[1]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,2,3,4,5\n" cool ","t</success>
    <attributes>[1]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>2,3,4,5\n" cool ","th</try>
    <as>
      <try>2,3,4,5\n" cool ","th</try>
      <success>,3,4,5\n" cool ","tha</success>
      <attributes>[2]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,3,4,5\n" cool ","tha</success>
    <attributes>[2]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>3,4,5\n" cool ","that</try>
    <as>
      <try>3,4,5\n" cool ","that</try>
      <success>,4,5\n" cool ","that'</success>
      <attributes>[3]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,4,5\n" cool ","that'</success>
    <attributes>[3]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>4,5\n" cool ","that's</try>
    <as>
      <try>4,5\n" cool ","that's</try>
      <success>,5\n" cool ","that's </success>
      <attributes>[4]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>,5\n" cool ","that's </success>
    <attributes>[4]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>5\n" cool ","that's "</try>
    <as>
      <try>5\n" cool ","that's "</try>
      <success>\n" cool ","that's ""</success>
      <attributes>[5]</attributes>
    </as>
    <success>\n" cool ","that's ""</success>
    <attributes>[5]</attributes>
  </field>
  <success>" cool ","that's ""n</success>
  <attributes>[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]</attributes>
</record>
<record>
  <try>" cool ","that's ""n</try>
  <field>
    <try>" cool ","that's ""n</try>
    <success>,"that's ""nice""","</success>
    <attributes>[ , c, o, o, l,  ]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>"that's ""nice""","n</try>
    <success>,"new\nline is accept</success>
    <attributes>[t, h, a, t, ', s,  , ", n, i, c, e, "]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>"new\nline is accepta</try>
    <success>,"bye"\n</success>
    <attributes>[n, e, w, 
, l, i, n, e,  , i, s,  , a, c, c, e, p, t, a, b, l, e]</attributes>
  </field>
  <field>
    <try>"bye"\n</try>
    <success>\n</success>
    <attributes>[b, y, e]</attributes>
  </field>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[ , c, o, o, l,  ], [t, h, a, t, ', s,  , ", n, i, c, e, "], [n, e, w, 
, l, i, n, e,  , i, s,  , a, c, c, e, p, t, a, b, l, e], [b, y, e]]</attributes>
</record>
<record>
  <try></try>
  <field>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </field>
  <fail/>
</record>
```

### Simpifying Matters

Still, since X3 is more "just C++" and less "magic" (compared to Qi) why not leverage that?

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/G63zfnTr6)**

```
//#include <regex>
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/multi_pass.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace parser {

    struct HeaderData {
        std::string col, col_type;
    };

 // using Header = std::vector<HeaderData>;
    using Field  = std::string;
    using Record = std::vector<Field>;

    struct error_base {
        template <typename It, typename E, typename Ctx>
        auto on_error(It&, It last, E const& x, Ctx const& context) const
        {
            It end = x.where();
            while (end != last && *end != '\n')
                end++;

            std::ostringstream stringStream;
            stringStream << "expecting a field here> "
                         << std::string(x.where(), end);

            auto& msg = x3::get<error_base>(context);
            msg   = stringStream.str();
            return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
        }
    };

    template <typename T> static inline auto as(auto p, char const* name = "as") {
        struct tag : error_base { };
        return x3::rule<tag, T>{name} = p;
    }

    auto make_record_parser(auto sep, std::string& msg,
                            [[maybe_unused]] int& newline_count)
    {
        using x3::ascii::char_;
        auto EOL      = x3::eol | x3::eoi;
        auto textdata = char_("-! ~@#$%^&*(){}[]<>.?a-zA-Z_0-9/\\+=|:;,'\t`") - sep;
        auto unquoted = as<Field>(*textdata);

        auto dblequote = "\"\"" >> x3::attr('"');
        auto quoted    = '"' >> *(dblequote | ~char_('"')) >> '"';

        auto field  = as<Field>(!x3::eoi >> (quoted | unquoted), "field");
        auto record = as<Record>((field % sep) > EOL, "record");
        return x3::with<error_base>(msg)[record];
    }

} // namespace parser

auto parseFile(fs::path filename)
{
    // int           _linenum = 1;
    std::string   _error_msg     = "success";
    char          _delimchar     = ',';
    int           _newline_count = 0;
    std::ifstream stream(filename);

    using Base  = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
    auto iter   = boost::spirit::make_default_multi_pass(Base(stream));

    std::vector<parser::Record> result;

    auto record = parser::make_record_parser( //
        _delimchar, // or explicitly: x3::as_parser(_delimchar),
        _error_msg, //
        _newline_count);

    if (!x3::parse(iter, {}, *record > x3::eoi, result))
        throw std::runtime_error("error: " + _error_msg);

    return result;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main()
{
    auto recs = parseFile("input.txt");
    fmt::print("Parsed: \n - {}\n", fmt::join(recs, "\n - "));
}
```

Giving the same output.

Comment: Thank you @sehe this solution solved my problem.